# Include html while keeping paths relative to file being included

Tags: php, html, include, relative-path

Have several html snippets that I want included in a 'parent' file.
The parent file contains relative paths.
These snippets also contain relative paths, relative to their location - not relative to the file they will be included into.
For example, one snippet is the header, common to all pages on the site.

```
<div style='background:url(img/bg.jpg)'>
  <img src='img/logo.png'>
</div>
```

This will be inserted into the existing page as follows:

```
  <div style='background:url(img/gradient.jpg)'>
    <?php include '../includes/header.txt'; ?>
  </div>
```

Example is **very greatly simplified**, the actual files have many paths.
I am NOT in control of the files that will be included.
Which means I cannot add PHP variables to the urls.

I also cannot make the paths absolute in any way.
For the included files - because I have no control over the html.
For all files - because the final pages are dev'd on several machines, and must work whether at http://www.mysite/myfile, http://localhost/mysite/myfile, or even http://127.0.0.1/~/anyuser/...

Some ideas I've had:

1. [php include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php1.1.): `include '../includes/header.txt';`

   - Paths come out relative to the file it has been included into.
2. Including each snippet as an iFrame:

   - Page layout isn't very iFrame friendly. Besides SEO & page load issues.
3. Parsing the page and replacing all paths using a parser.

   - The pages are not 100% valid HTML (no control over them) and the parser coughs and rolls over dead. Besides the ridiculous server load.
4. Using [base tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

   - Works beautifully in every real browser.
     But Internet Explorer 7, 8, and 9 just ignore the base tag (outside the head).
     One base tag *could* be declared in the head, but then all the other paths on the page (and probably in the CSS files) will be all wrong.

BaseTag Usage:

```
<?php
  echo "<base href='$path_to_includes_folder' />";
  include '../includes/header.txt';
  echo "<base href='$path_based_on___file__' />";
?>
```

As I understand, this exactly why the base tag was created, and is supported in every decent browser - so that we can, in the middle of one HTML file, tell the browser that I am about to include a second HTML file, and all paths should be relative to the new location. This worked beautifully in IE6, and I assume there must have been some logic in dropping support for it. Some logic which escaped Opera, Webkit, and Mozilla.
The only posts I can find on the subject laud Microsoft for dropping support, without giving even a hint of a reason why *dropping support* for something which is *an accepted standard* (in use in all browsers of the time) and *useful* is a good thing.

Now, I hate developing for IE with a passion, but cannot ignore it. They still have almost 1/3 of the users!

So, how to include php snippets with relative paths, and keep them relative to the file being included?

And can anyone please tell me if there is any reason at all MS dropped base support, or what can be done to help get it back?

Comment: Why would you place the base tag anywhere but in the head section? Are you wanting to include relative PHP scripts (server side) or images (client side)? It's not very clear from your question.

Comment: I don't find your question very clear, but it seems that it doesn't really have anything to do with include() or PHP. The result of an include() statement is the same as if the contents of the included file were pasted at that point in the source file. So just imagine this HTML was there in the first place, and you weren't using include(). Now your problem has nothing to do with include(), and is just about figuring out how you want to handle paths in your application. Maybe you should define a base URL for images somewhere higher level in the project and use that in your CSS.

Comment: @Phil - I am trying to include html that has in it paths to images, javascript, or CSS files. The reason I would place the base tag before the content that is included, is that the included content has a different root than the rest of the page, which is relative to the location object. If I put the base tag into the head it would make all the paths on the page relative to some other location... Why would I want that?

Comment: @Dan Grossman - The question was not about PHP's include(); It was how to use PHP to include a snippet while somehow keeping the paths in that snippet valid. And perhaps to understand why the previously accepted mechanism should have been dropped. There is no way to redefine a base URL just for images, but even if there were, it would knock out all of the images that are relative to the page.  As a third aside, why is this not normal - I have many uses for writing once as HTML and including it where needed.

Comment: @SamGoody - the base tag is and always has been only allowed in the head section. It's use effects all relative paths in `href` and `src` attributes. If this is not adequate for your needs (different bases for images and JS), you will need to update your **relative** paths manually.

Comment: @Phil Brown - Incorrect. Try pasting the following into http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_base_test. Notice that it works in Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox. IE6 requires a closing base tag, but it works there as well.      `<!doctype html><html>
<body>

Base: W3Schools<br>
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" >
<img src="stickman.gif" width="24" height="39" >

<br>
Base: Yahoo<br>
<base href="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/" >
<img src="yahoo_logo_us_061509.png"  >

</body>
</html>`

Comment: @SamGoody - I prefer to trust in the source rather than browser quirks - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4

Comment: FYI, the "tryit editor" test fails in Chromium 7.

Answer (score 1):

For these situations I use the following,

```
$PROTOCOL = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https' : 'http';
$DOC_ROOT = $PROTOCOL.'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

//The project path points to the root file (index.php, or whatever your index file is).
$projectRoot = dirname($DOC_ROOT.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/';
```

Then you could do (using your example)

```
<div style='background:url(<?php echo $projectRoot; ?>img/bg.jpg)'>
    <img src='img/logo.png'>
</div>
```

This will give you a dynamic absolute path.

Comment: I cannot put PHP into the paths, as I have no control over the HTML. Besides the tedious work of switching every path when there are over a hundred (in the example provided, there are two urls).